# Combo Errors MySQL gone away & Product Price :Cannot initialize the indexer process

Tags: magento-1.8, price, indexing, reindex, mysql-indexes

**Indexing** Stuck at **Processing** while Reindexing

And The **exception.log** shows Error as

> General error: 2006 MySQL server has gone away

The **Full *Exception.log*** Contents are as follows :

```
2014-06-17T11:55:38+00:00 DEBUG (7): Exception message: SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 2006 MySQL server has gone away
Trace: #0 /home/sabkafgs/public_html/lib/Varien/Db/Statement/Pdo/Mysql.php(110): Zend_Db_Statement_Pdo->_execute(Array)
#1 /home/sabkafgs/public_html/app/code/core/Zend/Db/Statement.php(291): Varien_Db_Statement_Pdo_Mysql->_execute(Array)
#2 /home/sabkafgs/public_html/lib/Zend/Db/Adapter/Abstract.php(479): Zend_Db_Statement->execute(Array)
#3 /home/sabkafgs/public_html/lib/Zend/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Abstract.php(238): Zend_Db_Adapter_Abstract->query('UPDATE `index_p...', Array)
#4 /home/sabkafgs/public_html/lib/Varien/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Mysql.php(428): Zend_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Abstract->query('UPDATE `index_p...', Array)
#5 /home/sabkafgs/public_html/lib/Zend/Db/Adapter/Abstract.php(632): Varien_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Mysql->query('UPDATE `index_p...', Array)
#6 /home/sabkafgs/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Index/Model/Resource/Process.php(137): Zend_Db_Adapter_Abstract->update('index_process', Array, Array)
#7 /home/sabkafgs/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Index/Model/Resource/Process.php(109): Mage_Index_Model_Resource_Process->_updateProcessData('2', Array)
#8 /home/sabkafgs/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Index/Model/Process.php(222): Mage_Index_Model_Resource_Process->failProcess(Object(Mage_Index_Model_Process))
#9 /home/sabkafgs/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Index/Model/Process.php(258): Mage_Index_Model_Process->reindexAll()
#10 /home/sabkafgs/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Index/controllers/Adminhtml/ProcessController.php(182): Mage_Index_Model_Process->reindexEverything()
#11 /home/sabkafgs/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(418): Mage_Index_Adminhtml_ProcessController->massReindexAction()
#12 /home/sabkafgs/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Router/Standard.php(250): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->dispatch('massReindex')
#13 /home/sabkafgs/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Front.php(172): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Router_Standard->match(Object(Mage_Core_Controller_Request_Http))
#14 /home/sabkafgs/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(354): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Front->dispatch()
#15 /home/sabkafgs/public_html/app/Mage.php(684): Mage_Core_Model_App->run(Array)
#16 /home/sabkafgs/public_html/index.php(87): Mage::run('', 'store')
#17 {main}
```

Any Solutions ??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Raise max_allowed_packet option in your's my.cnf

```
max_allowed_packet=16M
```

If it doesn't help try this https://github.com/magenx/magento-mysql mysql settings.

Comment: Can You Suggest me settings for cPanel ?